# root user renamed as qroot - unable to su or sudo

Tags: permissions, root, su

Mysteriously, on our public SSH server, root user is now showing up as qroot. All the files owned by root are now owned by qroot.

`id qroot` shows qroot is UID 0

`/etc/passwd` file is owned by qroot

`/etc/shadow` is readable only by qroot

`su -` says `su: user root does not exist`

`su qroot` says password is wrong (probably because `shadow` file mismatches)

What can I do to recover `root` user?

Fedora 14, plain `/etc/passwd` file based auth.

Comment: You should also mention in your question what `getent passwd root` tells you.

Comment: @JdeBP I get no response for getent passwd root Just blank prompt...

Comment: @GAD3R Yes, I stumbled on that link upon Googling already. Couldnt get any useful remedies from it..

Comment: Can you login as qroot using root's password?

Comment: is `sudo` installed? and configured to allow you to get a shell or run `sudo vipw` or similar?   if so, then do that.  Similarly, if you have an `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys` set up to allow password-less root access you can `ssh qroot@hostname` and edit `/etc/passwd`.  Otherwise, your best bet option would be to reboot to a rescue CD/USB-stick, mount the rootfs RW, and edit the /etc/passwd file to change `qroot` back to `root`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command:

```
sudo -u \#0 vi /etc/passwd
```

Then change the user name back to root.
For the explanation please visit: https://aslamlatheef.blogspot.com/2015/09/why-cant-i-sudo-unknown-user-root.html